# Infragistics2.WebUI.UltraWebGrid.v7 problems while running on windows 7 64bits

Tags: infragistics, windows-7-x64

i am new in using Infragistics, i have an application deployed on client server and it s working fine while browsing it from windows xp 32bits. But currently he want to navigate the application using windows 7 64bits. So how can i fix the problem without changing the dll version. i m currently using version 7 infragistics.

Comment: We are all here to help you to fix the problem. Just tell us what is the problem.

Comment: What specifically is the issue that is seen?  Using a 32 bit or 64 bit client machine shouldn't be a factor.  Are you using the same web browser on both machines?